# Extract subset of multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series, subset

My data look as follows (I have many more variables and groups in the dataset):

```
group   x   time
1   0   1636
1   0   1637
1   0   1638
1   1   1639
1   1   1640
1   1   1641
1   1   1642
2   0   1683
2   0   1684
2   0   1685
2   0   1686
2   0   1687
2   0   1688
2   1   1689
2   1   1690
2   1   1691
3   0   1638
3   1   1639
3   1   1640
```

Each `group` has its own time series (indicated by `time`). What I would need is a fixed number of observations before and after `x` takes the value of 1 for a certain group.
For example, always 3 observations immediately before x takes 1 and 3 observations from when it takes the value of 1 (so 3 observations right before and 3 right after). When there are not enough observations either before or after, I would like to remove the time series for that group.

Data would then look as follows:

```
group   x   time
1   0   1636
1   0   1637
1   0   1638
1   1   1639
1   1   1640
1   1   1641
2   0   1686
2   0   1687
2   0   1688
2   1   1689
2   1   1690
2   1   1691
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a unique `group_indices()` by `group` and `x`, then we filter groups that have fewer than 3 observations and `row_number()`s of observations where `x != 1` that are `%in%` the range `n()` (group size) to `n()-2` to keep only the 3 observations prior to a change of `x` occuring.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(g = group_indices_(., .dots = c("group", "x"))) %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  mutate(condition = ifelse(x == 1, NA, row_number())) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3, ifelse(is.na(condition), TRUE, condition %in% n():(n()-2)))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [13 x 5]
#Groups: g [4]
#
#   group     x  time     g condition
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
#1      1     0  1636     1         1
#2      1     0  1637     1         2
#3      1     0  1638     1         3
#4      1     1  1639     2        NA
#5      1     1  1640     2        NA
#6      1     1  1641     2        NA
#7      1     1  1642     2        NA
#8      2     0  1686     3         4
#9      2     0  1687     3         5
#10     2     0  1688     3         6
#11     2     1  1689     4        NA
#12     2     1  1690     4        NA
#13     2     1  1691     4        NA
```

You can optionally remove the `g` and `condition` columns by adding `select(-(g:condition))` to the chain.

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), x = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    time = c(1636L, 1637L, 1638L, 1639L, 1640L, 1641L, 1642L, 
    1683L, 1684L, 1685L, 1686L, 1687L, 1688L, 1689L, 1690L, 1691L, 
    1638L, 1639L, 1640L)), .Names = c("group", "x", "time"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This only keeps the initial 3 first observations per group, not the 3 observations right before x turns into 1. For example, for group 2, the time series jumps from 1685 to 1689, rather than keeping the observations 1688 1687 and 1686.

Comment: I might not have made myself entirely clear. Within group 2, observations '1686 1687' and '1688' are the observations right before x takes the value of 1. It are these 3 that I would like to extract, while currently '1683,1684' and '1685' are extracted. '1689 1690' and '1691' are the observations right after 'x' takes the value of 1, which are correctly taken now. Is this clear? So I would like to keep only '1686 1687' and '1688'

Comment: @research111 See if the updated solution works for you. You might want to edit your initial question to reflect the changes requested.

Comment: Nice one with `group_indices`

Comment: Final question.. It now unfortunately also selects the final 3 values after x=1 **within a group**. In my example I only had 3 observations with 1 within group, but sometimes it's 4 or 5. So in case of group 1, if there is an extra observation "group=1;x=1;time=1642", the selection is 1640,1641,1642 instead of 1639,1640,1641

Comment: So you want to keep all `x=1` that have group size larger than 3 and only apply the filter for "3 after x=1" on `x=0` ?

Comment: Yes. I added 1 observations in my sample data (1   1   1642), the result should stay the same regarless of the fact that the group size is larger than 3 afterx=1 within a group

Comment: @research111 See edit. As mentionned earlier, please also edit your initial requirements so it reflects your numerous additionnal precisions in comments.